# Images are blinking while updating JSON code with TimeInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

**Here is my JSON function**
**my userId is as below**

```
var userId = '@(ViewBag.UserId)';
        function getMessage(userId) {
            $.ajax(
                 {
                     type: "Post",
                     url: "/Message/GetMessage",
                     dataType: "json",
                     data: { "recieverUsersId": userId },
                     async: true,
                     cache:true,
                     success: function (data) {
                         var div = $('#msg');
                         div.html("");
                         $.each(data.messages, function (i, item) {
                         div.append('<li id="reply"><img src="' + item.FileAttachedURL + '" style="height:auto; width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "/></li>')
                         }, 
                         error: function (req, status, error) {
                         var div = $('#comment');
                         div.html("");
                         div.append('Error');
                     }
                 });
     }
```

**To Update JSON Data into time interval**

```
     function getValue() {
         var userId = $('#recieverUserId').val();
         getMessage(userId)
         function myStopFunction() {
             clearInterval(myVar);
         }
     }
```

**Set time interval for  getMessage function**

```
     var refresh = setInterval(function () { getValue() }, 5);
     function myStopFunction() {
         clearInterval(refresh);
     }
```

**Problem : when i am getting Images from table Images are also blinking in time interval. why i am getting this problem or is there any other solution to update data in a certain time period**

Comment: Your code is issuing an asynchronous ajax request every 5 milliseconds and processing the result when it arrives.  You're not leaving the browser any CPU time to actually re-render the page.

Comment: Not to mention that this request fires another request regardless of whether or not the previous has completed. This is not a good idea!

Comment: Is there any other method to hit the method in certain time period or call method with json after table is getting one other value in it..?

Comment: @tymeJV the what i have to do... i want to all message from the table without reloading the we page...?

Comment: @tymeJV can you tell me how to render a partial view of action result using ajax